# Protecting Python Data Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, python, security

i have a doubt about protection of Python Code. I'm not meaning just "Obfuscation", so, i've read a lot of topics about this subject, and i choose to put my application behind a web interface. So, it's done.

I execute my code trough a CGI script behind a Web interface, so, i don't need to send my .py file anymore.

But, i still have concern about protection.

Is there some well known manual where i can find information about Apache and how to protect my home directory against "undesirable downloads"?? So, my .py file (real code) is not acessed directly, but, it's there. So, how can i protect it in a efficient way, considering that i'm using a Apache2 server?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be 99,9% sure that your python files can't be downloaded put them outside the document tree of the web-server and make sure that your scripts are secure (check links below):

[Local File Inclusion Explained](http://hakipedia.com/index.php/Local_File_Inclusion)

[Remote file Inclusion Explained](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_file_inclusion)

Don't forget to set correct file permissions for your scripts. You might also want to disable some database functions like LOAD_FILE(), which is typically used only by hackers.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend. But, i saw the most part of these articles are about PHP. Do you know something about sintax in Python to implement this kind of security level??

Comment: Same rule goes for every language: don't trust user-supplied data - if user-supplied data is not sufficiently sanitized, local and remote users might be able to execute sql queries, shell commands, read your files, etc. Make sure to check all your code that is using user-supplied data.